# Bidouble covers and the pushforward of the canonical bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In his paper "Singular bidouble covers and the construction of interesting algebraic surfaces", Catanese gives the  following theorem

**Theorem:** *Let $f:Y\to X$ be a finite flat $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2$-Galois cover with $X$ an algebraic variety in char$(k)\neq 2$. Then there exist 3 Cartier divisors $D_j = div(x_j)$ on $X$ and 3 line bundles $L_i$, with fibre coordinater $w_i$, such that $Y$ is embedded in the total space of the vector line bundle $L_1\oplus L_2 \oplus L_3$.*

He goes on giving the decompositions
$$f_*\mathcal{O}_Y \cong \mathcal{O}_X \oplus \bigoplus_i \mathcal{O}_X(-L_i),$$
and
$$f_*\omega_Y\cong\omega_X\oplus\bigoplus_i\omega_X(L_i).$$

Finally he states that locally one can take the square roots $y_1^2=x_1$, $y_2^2 = x_2$ and $y_3^2=x_3$, which define a Galois $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$ cover $Z$ for which $Y$ is the quotient of $Z$ by the involution multiplying all the three functions $y_i$ by $-1$.

According to Catanese, this remark, alongside with the fact that the action of the Galois group satisfy:

- $\sigma_iy_i=-y_i$,
- $\sigma_ky_i=y_i$ for $k\neq i$.

Allows us to write

$$f_*\omega_Y\cong y_1y_2y_3\omega_X\oplus\bigoplus_i y_i\omega_X(L_i).$$

**So, my question is:** Why does the remark and the action of the Galois group allow us to introduce these factors $y_1y_2y_3$ and $y_i$ in the equation?